# How can I get a list of orders greater than a specific order number in VB.Net?

Tags: magento-1.9, vb.net

I'm really struggling with this.  Situation:

I am trying to import a list of orders from a Magento site.  I only want orders with an increment_id greater than 800009, for example.

Using filters like this:

```
Private Function GetOrderList(startOrderNo As String)

    Dim ae As New GrendeneWebService.associativeEntity
    Dim params As New GrendeneWebService.filters
    ae.key = "increment_id"
    ae.value = startOrderNo

    params.filter = New GrendeneWebService.associativeEntity() {ae}


    Dim orderListEntity = New GrendeneWebService.salesOrderListEntity()
    Dim orderListResponse = New GrendeneWebService.salesOrderListResponse
    Dim orderlistRequest = New GrendeneWebService.salesOrderListRequest(sessionID, params)

    Dim orderList() 

    orderListResponse = mage.salesOrderList(orderlistRequest)

    orderList = orderListResponse.result

    Return orderList



End Function
```

I can get the order number that I pass to the function, but I want every order with a number GREATER THAN OR EQUAL to the order number passed.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is really not a Magento question, but increment_id does not have to be a number, but if you want to check only number why don't you CAST your increment_id then select all the orders that are greater than that number?

Comment: Hi  Well, it is a Magento question because I am struggling with getting the Magento filters to work in VB.Net.  I can get a list of all orders and then select orders greater then my input number from the result.  However, for efficiency it would be better to ONLY return the orders with a number greater than or equal to the number I pass to the function (BTW, increment_id is a number in this setup)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a VB.net question and not specifically Magento

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can you say this is not related to Magento when what I am doing is trying to connect to Magento via VB.Net?  If I posted this under VB.Net I would have the following issues:  1. It is not strictly a VB.Net question so it would be voted to close by someone like you.  2. I probably wouldn't reach the audience required to answer my query (ie Magento users / developers).

Answer (score 2):

In PHP it is:

```
$params = array(array(
        'complex_filter' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'increment_id',
                array(
                    'lt' => 800009
                )
            ),
        )
    ));

$result = $client->__call('salesOrderList', $params);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ;-)  I can manage this in PHP - I'm struggling to translate the syntax to VB though